# Android softInput on done click does not closes Action tool bar(Copy/paste bar still remains on screen)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard

**Problem**: I am facing an issue in my fragments. When i click on edit text input field softInput keyboard opens and while keyboard is open when i long press on edit text field it opens system action bar [copy,paste,select all]. After clicking on softInput done(IME action) button sofinput(Keyboard closes) but action bar still appears on the screen it does not closes or disappear. After clicking anywhere on screen Action bar still remains open.

So how to resolve this issue on "done" click of softinput(keyboard) my system actionBar should also closes.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thank you for this. can you also prvide with me ans if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the solution in edit text field.

```
edittext.clearFocus()
```

Action bar will disappear